# Simple protections for write access Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need a simple way to stop anyone from copying the code below into their inspector tool to add false scores. There are no users, I just want to restrict write access from the browser. Is there a way to do this with security rules in Firebase Realtime Database? Right now I just have    ".read": true, ".write": true, and validations.

```js
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("scores")
          .push({
            name: name,
            score: score
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit write access to only the users signed into your app/project with Firebase Authentication (including [anonymous users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)), your write rule should minimally contain what's suggested in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security):

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

Comment: I haven't found a way for the SDK to differentiate between code executed from my js file vs. from any other browser-side code. So authentication hasn't been helpful?