# Only allow logged in users to read and write Firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using FireBase Realtime Database to setup a simple CRUD app.

I'm setting up my rules so only logged in users can write to the requests section.  I must be misunderstanding something about auth.uid.

In requests I have set `".write" : "auth.uid === true"`, but am unable to write data.

What am I missing here?

```
{
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$user_id" : {
      ".read" : "$user_id === auth.uid",
      ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid"
    }
  },
  "requests" : {
    ".read" : "true",
    ".write" : "auth.uid === true",
    "$request_id" : {
      ".validate" : "newData.hasChildren(['createdAt', 'note', 'requestedBy', 'title', 'type'])",
        "createdAt": {
          ".validate" : "newData.isNumber()"
        },
        "note": {
          ".validate" : "newData.isString()"
        },
        "requestedBy": {
          ".validate" : "newData.isString()"
        },
        "title": {
          ".validate" : "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"
        },

        "type": {
          ".validate" : "newData.isString()"
        },
        "$other" : {
          ".validate" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auth.uid` is a string, so it will never `=== true`. I think you want `auth.uid != null`

Comment: Yep, I just found that in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517159/simple-protections-for-write-access-firebase-realtime-database?rq=1

Thanks!